# modify gff coordinates without changing the CDS and exon coordinates

Tags: linux, awk

I am trying to change the coordinates of genes and mRNAs in my gff. I want other entries like CDS and mRNA to not be affected by my code and still be listed as it is in my output. The code that I used gives me syntax error. Need to know how can i get the desired output.

my input gff:

```
Chr01  xyz     gene    210262  212819  .       -       .       ID=Chr01.g13944
Chr01  xyz     mRNA    210262  212819  .       -       .       ID=Chr01.g13944;Parent=Chr01.g13944
Chr01  xyz     CDS     210262  210528  .       -       0       ID=Chr01.g13944.cds;Parent=Chr01.g13944
Chr01  xyz     exon    210262  210528  .       -       .       ID=Chr01.g13944.exon4;Parent=Chr01.g13944
Chr01  xyz     CDS     210622  210728  .       -       2       ID=Chr01.g13944.cds;Parent=Chr01.g13944
Chr01  xyz     exon    210622  210728  .       -       .       ID=Chr01.g13944.exon3;Parent=Chr01.g13944
Chr01  xyz     CDS     210933  212121  .       -       0       ID=Chr01.g13944.cds;Parent=Chr01.g13944
Chr01  xyz     exon    210933  212121  .       -       .       ID=Chr01.g13944.exon2;Parent=Chr01.g13944
Chr01  xyz     CDS     212730  212819  .       -       0       ID=Chr01.g13944.cds;Parent=Chr01.g13944
Chr01  xyz    exon    212730  212819  .       -       .       ID=Chr01B.g13944.exon1;Parent=Chr01B.g13944
```

Desired output:

```
Chr01  xyz     gene    210162  212919  .       -       .       ID=Chr01.g13944
Chr01  xyz     mRNA    210162  212919  .       -       .       ID=Chr01.g13944;Parent=Chr01.g13944
Chr01  xyz     CDS     210262  210528  .       -       0       ID=Chr01.g13944.cds;Parent=Chr01.g13944
Chr01  xyz     exon    210262  210528  .       -       .       ID=Chr01.g13944.exon4;Parent=Chr01.g13944
Chr01  xyz     CDS     210622  210728  .       -       2       ID=Chr01.g13944.cds;Parent=Chr01.g13944
Chr01  xyz     exon    210622  210728  .       -       .       ID=Chr01.g13944.exon3;Parent=Chr01.g13944
Chr01  xyz     CDS     210933  212121  .       -       0       ID=Chr01.g13944.cds;Parent=Chr01.g13944
Chr01  xyz     exon    210933  212121  .       -       .       ID=Chr01.g13944.exon2;Parent=Chr01.g13944
Chr01  xyz     CDS     212730  212819  .       -       0       ID=Chr01.g13944.cds;Parent=Chr01.g13944
Chr01  xyz    exon    212730  212819  .       -       .       ID=Chr01B.g13944.exon1;Parent=Chr01B.g13944
```

`awk -F '\t' '{if ($3 ~ /gene/ || $3 ~ /mRNA/) print $1,$2,$3,$4-100,$5+100,$6,$7,$8,$9 || if ($3 ~ /CDS/ || $3 ~ /exon/) print$0}' input.gff > out.gff`

Comment: Please remember that this site isn't specific to bioinformatics. This means that you need to explain details like the fact that GFF is a tab-separated format and that the `gene` needs to be the value of the third field etc since folks here won't know these things. You are very welcome to post these questions here (although you might also want to check out our sister site, [bioinformatics.se]), just make sure to phrase your questions as general text processing issues, that don't require prior bioinformatics knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\t" }
 ($3=="gene" || $3=="mRNA"){ $4-=100; $5+=100 }1' infile
```

this only changes the coordinates of the "gene" and "mRNA" type genomes and leave the other types unchanged.

Comment: Could you also explain the purpose of 1 at the end of code?

Comment: @Gavin see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26005295/awk-splitting-a-string-into-sub-strings-with-length-n/26005809?noredirect=1#comment131041164_26005809